# "is" or "are" for x and y?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

The boy and girl is going to the store.
The boy and girl are going to the store.

Which sentence is correct? I can't remember if 'x and y' is considered a singular or plural noun.

Comment: I'm confused as to why this question was closed. This page was the first result when I tried searching this issue online, and the question seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct sentence is :

> The boy and the girl are going to the store.

The boy **and** the girl : **plural subject**

Comment: plural subject, singular nouns. :)