# Can this sentence be written in both forms?

Tags: conjunctions

I seem to remember learning a rule that the following sentence should be written like this (because of the conjunction "and") :

**The future strength AND long-term stability of our company ARE rooted in a disciplined risk management strategy.**

However, I'm seeing the singular 'is" used a lot in the company I work for:

**The future strength AND long-term stability of our company IS rooted in a disciplined risk management strategy.**

My question is whether or not they are both acceptable?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/is-or-are-for-x-and-y

Answer (score -1):

The first is correct, and the second is not.

It's OK though because nobody pays much attention to such puffery.

Comment: Hey Jeff. Thanks for your comment. I'm curious about your "puffery" comment though. I was curious about the structure of the sentence, so that means SOMEbody paid attention. Although I use this site frequently, this is the first question I posted. Do responses normally take the tone you've offered here?