# Tom and Julia are "husband and wife" or "_a_ husband and wife"

Tags: articles

I saw this sentence in a book:

> Tom, 45, and Julia, 40, are husband and wife.

It sounded natural to me not to use the article "a" before "husband and wife". But I'd like to know the grammatical explanation.

Comment: This is all tangled up in the messy topic of when to use (or not use) "the indefinite article".  A lot has to do with context.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["is" or "are" for x and y?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151425/is-or-are-for-x-and-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an idiom.

In idioms articles are often omitted.

According to [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/husband%20and%20wife):

idiom

***husband and wife***

: a married couple

// They were husband and wife for almost 60 years.

And  have a look at [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20husband%20and%20wife%2C%20are%20a%20husband%20and%20wife&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20husband%20and%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20a%20husband%20and%20wife%3B%2Cc0).

It adds some statistics to the previous information.

By the way, according to [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/husband-and-wife) 
it is a hyphenated adjective:

"***husband-and-wife***

ADJECTIVE

Relating to or involving a husband and wife; consisting of a husband and wife."

In this case there's no problem of using or not using the indefinite article here because adjectives as predicatives are used without articles.

Comment: Oh that was a quick answer, many thanks. I had looked it up on google but never as an idiom. It makes sense now.

Comment: The fact that it's "husband and wife" has little to do with it.  The same issues would arise with "doctor and patient".

Comment: I know M-W defines *husband and wife* as an idiom, but I'd dispute this, as it doesn't fit M-W's own definition of [idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idiom): the meaning is readily deducible from the words, and the grammar isn't peculiar to this one expression [as @HotLicks notes, and I'd add "friend and foe", "master and servant", "brother and sister", "predator and prey", etc]. The reason for no determiner is more to do with it being problematic to have a determiner just for the first element of a pair of nouns, and too wordy as "a husband and his wife".

Comment: Perhaps the are nouns used as adjectives, comparable to “black and blue” in “my knees were black and blue.”

Comment: However, if you were going on to say more about these people than just stating their relationship, you could say something like _Tom and Julia are a husband and wife who live in New York_.

Comment: That's right as here we mean one of the family pairs in this city.

Comment: You wouldn't say "*a* husband and wife" because there are two of them.  You wouldn't say "*a* husband and *a* wife" because that could me they are both married - but not to each other!  Effectively you're saying that they are "a pair" or "a couple".

Comment: Also we can say just ''They are married''.

Comment: ''...to each other'' to be more exact.